# Zoom image over side divs

Tags: css, image, hover, zooming

I'm creating this landing page: https://oakfield.online/

To give more focus on the image, I've tried to create a zoom effect on mouse hover. The objective is 50% achieved, the only thing that I couldn't do was to make the `img` tag to be on top of the columns beside that image.

This is the result:

[image: result]

There is my css hover code for the `img`:

```
.box-imagem img:hover {
    z-index: 999999;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
}
```

Any ideas about what should work?

Thanks!

Comment: `z-index` won't work with `position: static` (default position). Use `position: relative` or  `position: absolute`

Comment: @Morpheus, I've tried that to

Comment: My bad, I've not seen that you are using `display: flex`, so the first comment is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.tcb-flex-col.tve_empty_dropzone:hover {
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

Play with that - your containers are fighting for powerrrrr. :)

Comment: No problem, looks great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in two ways

1)

```
.tcb-flex-col>.tve_empty_dropzone:hover {
        z-index: 9999999;
    }
```

2)

```
.tcb-flex-col.tve_empty_dropzone:hover {
        z-index: 9999999;
    }
```